# UTF-8 No acepta caracteres especiales PostgreSQL-SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Buenos días he creado una base de datos para almacenar todos los paises y ciudades y estoy tratando de cargar la data pero a pesar de que mi base de datos esta creada con un enconde utf-8 al igual que mis tablas. Al momento de importar tambien selecciono UTF-8 pero me da error de este tipo `ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xe3 0x6f 0x20
CONTEXT:  COPY ciudades, line 23488` simplemente por recibir un acento, una ñ o cualquier otro caracter especial. Cualquier orientación que me puedan ayudar estaría agradecido.

A continuación el codigo SQL:

```html
-- Database: paises

-- DROP DATABASE paises;

CREATE DATABASE paises
    WITH 
    OWNER = postgres
    ENCODING = 'UTF8'
    LC_COLLATE = 'en_US.UTF-8'
    LC_CTYPE = 'en_US.UTF-8'
    TABLESPACE = pg_default
    CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;

-- La configuracion de la tabla

-- Table: public.ciudades

-- DROP TABLE public.ciudades;

CREATE TABLE public.ciudades
(
id_ciudad bigint NOT NULL,
id_pais_ciudad character varying(10) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
nom_ciudad character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
CONSTRAINT ciudades_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id_ciudad),
CONSTRAINT id_pais_ciudad FOREIGN KEY (id_pais_ciudad)
    REFERENCES public.paises (cod_pais) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.ciudades
OWNER to postgres;
```

Comment: Aquí falta el código copy que utilizas. Y lo más probable es que estés utilizando Unicode a la hora de guardar el archivo SQL, y por eso se queja UTF-8

Comment: Tengo una hoja excel y la estoy guardando en csv y estoy tratando de importar el csv a una tabla ya creada

Comment: Comprueba con un editor que posea conversión a UTF-8 en tu sistema operativo favorito qué tipo de codificación de caracteres tiene.

Parece que usas windows y eso usa Windows-1252. Es una sospecha, no te estoy confirmando que lo sea.

Comment: Cuando guardo el archivo le doy
1. Guardar como CSV Separado por comas
2. Entro a la opción herramientas - opciones web- codificación 
Y selecciono Unicode UTF-8

Comment: ¿Este código SQL que utilizas, también está en un archivo? ¿O utilizas PgAdmin? De ser así, la raíz de tu problema está en otro sitio.

Comment: Hice lo que me recomendaste, abri el archivo con bloc de notas y apesar de que lo habia guardado en Excel en UTF-8 estaba en formato ANSI. Procedi a guardarlo con el bloc de notas en utf-8 y la data subió perfecto. Gracias, coloca tu respuesta larga para aceptartela como correcta. Nuevamente Gracias por la orientación.

Comment: Era lo que me decias el archivo no se estaba guardando en utf-8. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Tu problema

Tienes un problema de codificación a la hora de suministrarle datos a la BD (base de datos). La base de datos espera `UTF-8` y le das otra cosa que no es esto.

### Problema de codificación

Tu problema radica en que tienes en alguna parte de los datos que introduces la codificación errónea.

Si usas Windows, suele ocurrir que tiene una codificación *ANSI*, *Windows-1252* o, si estás en algún país de habla no hispana, incluso hasta otra codificación.

Tal como has comentado, le introduces los datos desde un archivo utilizando CSV. Pues bien, al hacerlo así, incluso aunque el programa que exporta datos te diga que está en codificación `UTF-8`, puede que no lo sea.

Deberás asegurarte que, tanto la query, como los datos introducidos, estén correctamente codificados en `UTF-8`.